# String formatting of floats

Tags: python

I would like to convert a number to a string in such a way that it only shows a certain number of significant digits, without superfluous zeros. The following is an example of some desired in/outputs, given that I want 5 significant digits:

```
0.0000123456789 > 1.2346e-5
0.00123456789 > 1.2346e-3
0.123456789 > 1.2346e-1
1.23456789 > 1.2346
1234.56789 > 1234.6
1234567.89 > 1.2346e6
```

The `g` option of string formatting (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) comes pretty close, but its behaviour isn't quite what I'm looking for for numbers smaller than 1, but not *much* smaller than 1:

```
"{:.5g}".format(0.000123456789) # returns '0.00012346', I want '1.2346e-4'
```

Is it possible to manipulate the behaviour of one of the existing formatters to do this?

Comment: See https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @PeterWood: I'd come across that before asking the question, but didn't (and still don't) an answer there that suits me. If you see it, please post it below and get rep. :P

Comment: You are going to have some if statements to print the format you want, you do know that right ?

Comment: I kindly request the downvoter of this question to supply feedback on how I could have improved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'{:.4g}'.format(float(input)) if x<=1000 or x>=.0001 else '{:.4e}'.format(float(input))
```

Comment: Doesn't work as I want it to for numbers between 10 and 10000: those get turned into scientific format as well, even though that's not needed. (E.g. I prefer "123.46" over "1.2346e2", up to 10^(num_digits).)

Comment: Now you were close. I ended up going with `form = "e" if (x < 1) or (x >= 10**n) else "g"`; `return ("{:." + str(n) + form + "}").format(float(x))`, where `n` is the number of digits I want. I'll still accept it though, because you were right in spirit, if not exactly in letter. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need `e`, not `g`:

```
"{:.5g}".format(0.000123456789)
# '1.23457e-04'
```

Though the number in the format string indicates the amount of decimal points, so you'll want 4 (plus the one digit to the left of the decimal point):

```
"{:.4e}".format(0.000123456789)
'1.2346e-04'
```

Comment: Doesn't work as I want it to for numbers between 10 and 10000: those get turned into scientific format as well, even though that's not needed. (E.g. I prefer "123.46" over "1.2346e2", up to 10^(num_digits).)

Answer (score 0):

```
if 1 <= x <10000:
    print '{:.5g}'.format(x)

elif 1 > x  or x >= 10000:
    print '{:.4e}'.format(x)
```

Similar to A.Kot's answer but not a one liner and outputs what you want given your sample.